# Issues with deployment on heroku from Django

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I am needing help with deploying my Django app to heroku. My Django project works locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, the app crashes and cant load the index/home page. I'm not quite sure what the issue is with the GET request.

here are the `heroku logs --tail`:

```
2021-09-22T20:25:16.636085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn solarsystem.wsgi`
2021-09-22T20:25:17.678063+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-09-22T20:25:17.678545+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:34748 (4)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.678598+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-09-22T20:25:17.681856+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685446+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685447+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685455+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685455+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685456+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685457+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685458+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685458+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685458+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685459+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685460+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685460+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685460+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685461+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685461+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685461+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685462+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solarsystem.wsgi'
2021-09-22T20:25:17.685525+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.705927+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710035+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710037+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710038+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710039+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710039+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710039+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710040+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710040+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710040+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710041+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710041+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710041+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710042+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710043+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710043+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710043+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710044+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710044+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710044+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710045+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solarsystem.wsgi'
2021-09-22T20:25:17.710149+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-09-22T20:25:17.716907+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-09-22T20:25:17.815963+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-09-22T20:25:17.816003+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-09-22T20:25:18.009217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-09-22T20:25:18.098544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-22T20:25:18.108568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-22T20:25:25.900935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn solarsystem.wsgi`
2021-09-22T20:25:27.177917+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-09-22T20:25:27.178374+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24186 (4)
2021-09-22T20:25:27.178441+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-09-22T20:25:27.181781+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185297+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185298+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185307+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185307+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185307+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185308+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185308+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185309+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185309+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185309+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185310+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185310+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185310+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185311+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185311+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185311+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185312+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185312+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185313+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185313+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solarsystem.wsgi'
2021-09-22T20:25:27.185361+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-09-22T20:25:27.209899+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-09-22T20:25:27.209934+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-22 20:25:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-09-22T20:25:27.372467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-09-22T20:25:27.443605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-22T20:25:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

mainly here is where I see the issue (this is last two lines of logs):

```
2021-09-22T20:25:38.424383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mobius-7.herokuapp.com request_id=d6aab0b1-1ef3-4432-b681-e9eb6abb641b fwd="76.115.207.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-22T20:25:38.786726+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mobius-7.herokuapp.com request_id=c99bfa40-9d95-4974-968d-789668b49f29 fwd="76.115.207.199" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'space',
    'material',
    'sass_processor',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'solarsystem.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'solarsystem.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
# Configure Django App for Heroku.
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Procfile:
`web: gunicorn solarsystem.wsgi`

Comment: Unrelated, but now you've shared your secret key with the world you should immediately generate a new one! This shouldn't be in your settings file anyway - should be set via an env var or a secret...

Comment: @michjnich true, but im not doing any backend or DB stuff with this app, so I dont really care hahah

Comment: No, those two lines aren't the important ones. This is much more significant: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solarsystem.wsgi'`. Please [edit] your question and show your directory structure. (Your app probably fails to run locally, too, if you run via `heroku local`.)

Comment: @Chris you are correct, I saw that when I was looking into it further. I was able to get that portion to work, I managed to misplace the procfile location... 

BUT now there's a whole new issue. i going to revise the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting the code and looking at Chris's comment (especially with the `heroku local` command I learned, I realized that I had misplaced the `Procfile` one level too high. this particular issue is resolved.

`Procfile` should be in the project root dir.